# GCM error or curl syntax incorrect?

Tags: curl, syntax, google-cloud-messaging

I execute this command:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=$api_key" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

and get this:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:  -d; nodename nor servname provided, or not known
curl: (3) [globbing] nested braces not supported at pos 21
```

Is the syntax of the curl command incorrect or is it something with the Google servers?

Comment: I am getting the same thing

Answer (score 2):

First Get a GCM API key:
Go through the following process.
Step #1: Log into https://cloud.google.com/console with your Google account

Step #2: In the navigation on the left, go into "APIs & auth > APIs"

Step #3: Find "Google Cloud Messaging for Android" and click the "OFF" button next to it (note: this might involve then agreeing to additional terms of service)

Step #4: In the navigation on the left, go into "APIs & auth > Registered apps"

Step #5: Wait a really long time, apparently.

Step #6: Click the red REGISTER APP button.

Step #7: Give the app a name and choose Web Application, then click Register

Step #8: Click the "Server Key" section for your server key

And then get a Device notification ID .

curl --header "Authorization: key=XXXXXXX" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\":[\"ABC\"]}"